# Nextcloud - Automatically login the user via link

Tags: nextcloud, owncloud

I use the nextcloud API in my app. I use it to create the user accounts on nextcloud, for example. The users registers in my app and should not have to create their own Nextcloud password (my app does that for them).
Now I want to send the user to the Nextcloud page via a link. Can I create the link so that the user is automatically signed in? So e.g. if I pass a token via URL parameter?

Example:

```
https://myprivatenextcloud.com/...?user=user1&pwtoken=02jw9dj0w9djw02ejf0j0s9d2sldfk
```

Comment: Apps should not use a user's password to interact with nextcloud. Instead nextcloud offers the option to create app tokens which can be used by apps to authorize themselves. Take a look at the documentation: 
https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/developer_manual/client_apis/LoginFlow/index.html#converting-to-app-passwords So instead of a URL which contains the credentials (which is insecure) you should perform a request like shown in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I know the Nextcloud API documentation. The goal was not to send a username and password, but to use a token or the apppassword to login the user. My app is a homepage and here I would like to create a link (with e.g. the token as a parameter) with which the user is immediately logged in to nextcloud without the user having to worry about the nextcloud password.

Comment: I do not see a way for this ... An app you implement, which is authorized by a token (you'd have to setup tokens for _each_ user ...), certainly could create a user session. But I fail to see how you could forward that session to the user's browser.